# What is the sum of degree centrality called?

Tags: graph-theory, network

I have used the sum of degree centrality, which is the sum of all the edges in an undirected network, as a feature for a machine learning algorithm. But I am not sure if there is any terminology for this. If I want to justify this are there any references to this?

Comment: The sum of all degrees (or degree centralities) will be twice the number of edges.

Answer (score 1):

The "size" of a graph is its [number of edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory).